# Requesting support in implementing AR.js coding sequences; "Loading" issue

Tags: github, augmented-reality, ar.js

I want to set up an online store AR try-one features. However, when I implement the coding on the AR.js github page, I keep getting a "loading" on my computer, and on my mobile device it displays "Access this site over HTTPS to enter VR mode and grant access to the device sensors."

I would greatly appreciate some help in this matter.

Kind regards,
AURLab

Comment: "*Access this site over HTTPS*" - Secure the website where you are hosting your website with a SSL certifcate?